# How can i force Highcharts to use same symbols in Legend and Series?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

i try to draw multiple series with specific symbols(Highcharts standard symbols). But the symbols in series and in legend dont match. In series they are displayed correctly, but in legends they are kind of random...

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ogkh77r7/1/

```
$(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        "chart":{
        "zoomType":"xy", 
        "renderTo":"container"
    }, 
    "title":{
        "text":null
    }, 
    "subtitle":{
        "text":"text"
    }, 
    "xAxis":{
        "min": - 14, 
        "max":25, 
        "title":{
            "text":"text"
        }, 
        "tickPositions":[ - 14, - 10, - 5, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25], 
        "plotLines":[{
            "color":"#C0D0E0", 
            "width":1, 
            "value": - 14}]
    }, 
    "yAxis":{
        "title":{
            "text":"text"
        }, 
        "min":0, 
        "max":967
    }, 
    "plotOptions":{
        "series":{
            "marker":{
                "enabled":true
            }
        }
    }, 
    "tooltip":{
        "shared":false, 
        "useHTML":true, 
        "formatter":null, 
        "style":{
            "border":"none !important", 
            "padding":"0px", 
            "font-size":"1em"
        }
    }, 
    "series":[{
            "type":"line", 
            "name":"s1", 
            "zIndex":20, 
            "data":[
                {"x": - 14, "y":560.944, "marker":{"symbol":"circle"}}, 
                {"x":15.333, "y":0, "marker":{"symbol":"circle"}}
            ]
        },{
            "type":"line", 
            "name":"s2",
            "zIndex":19, 
            "data":[
                {"x": - 14, "y":5.848, "marker":{"symbol":"circle"}}, 
                {"x":25, "y":5.848, "marker":{"symbol":"circle"}}
            ]
        },{
            "type":"scatter", 
            "name":"s3", 
            "zIndex":10, 
            "data":[
                {"x":0.8, "y":266.667, "marker":{"symbol":"circle"}}, 
                {"x":2.513, "y":242.857, "marker":{"symbol":"circle"}}, 
                {"x":1.675, "y":253.571, "marker":{"symbol":"circle"}}
            ]
        },{
            "type":"scatter", 
            "name":"s4", 
            "zIndex":9, 
            "data":[
                {"x":13.263, "y":35.119, "marker":{"symbol":"diamond"}}, 
                {"x":16.989, "y":13.021, "marker":{"symbol":"diamond"}}, 
                {"x":16.2, "y":9.375, "marker":{"symbol":"diamond"}}
            ]
        }, {
            "type":"scatter", 
            "name":"s5", 
            "zIndex":30, 
            "data":[
                {"x": - 14, "y":650.19492, "marker":{"radius":6, "symbol":"triangle"}}
            ]
        }, {
            "type":"scatter", 
            "name":"s6", 
            "zIndex":30, 
            "data":[
                {"x":15, "y":5.8, "marker":{"radius":6, "symbol":"triangle-down"}}
            ]
        }
        ], 
        "colors":["#2f7ed8", "#2f7ed8", "#b2b2b2", "#c4c4c4", "#f15c80", "#f15c80"]
    });
});
```

I use Highcharts and Highstock on the same page, so i need to use highstock.js. Using highcharts.js dont fix the problem anyway.

Would be amazing if someone could help me with this, but i guess its a bug in Highcharts?

So long,
RaTm7

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to set your marker definitions on the series, not the data.

```
    {
        "type":"scatter", 
        "name":"s4", 
        "zIndex":9, 
        "marker": {
            "symbol": "diamond"
        },              
        "data":[
            {"x":13.263, "y":35.119}, 
            {"x":16.989, "y":13.021}, 
            {"x":16.2, "y":9.375}
        ]
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8ma4ts9s/

Comment: Ahh, thanks! It wasnt in the documentation, so i thought i dont work like that. It helps a lot!

Comment: you can find it now in doc http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.marker.symbol